# How to write in superscript in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, superscript

I am writing a code which is supposed to print a series in the form:

> x - (x^2)/2! + (x^3)/3! - (x^4)/4! ... (x^n)/n!

where x and n are input from the user end.

For now my code looks like this

```
x = int(input('Enter number: '))
n = int(input('Till which term? '))

#for series
for i in range(1,n+1,1):
    if i == n:
        print('('+str(x)+'^'+str(i)+')'+'/'+str(i)+'!')
    elif i == 1:
        print(str(x),end = ' - ')
    else:
        if i%2 != 0:
            print('('+str(x)+'^'+str(i)+')'+'/'+str(i)+'!',end = ' - ')
        else:
            print('('+str(x)+'^'+str(i)+')'+'/'+str(i)+'!',end = ' + ')
```

but the output is:

> ================= RESTART: E:/Python/Files/special series 4.py =================
> Enter number: 3
> Till which term? 6
> 3 - (3^2)/2! + (3^3)/3! - (3^4)/4! + (3^5)/5! - (3^6)/6!

is there any function to write in superscript to avoid the arrow-head sign?

Comment: There are superscript numbers in the Unicode table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Answer (score 0):

As the output of Python and pretty much any language is usually in unicode or ASCII, the answer is simply no.

Comment: You can save and render it as an image but yes, not in console.